# Sending notification from one app to another app in another device in Android

Tags: android, notifications, device

I am creating *two different ANDROID apps* (each on two separate devices and different locations), one for the *user* and another for the *merchant*. Here, I need to send a notification from the merchant's app to the user's app and vice versa  via a button clicks (both typically being on different devices, but both ANDROIDS), which the notification should be a popup or a dialog. I'm truly embarrassed by this concept. Could some one help me on this. A sample full source code would be really appreciable, since I am a beginner in ANDROID.
Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 2):

use google GCM service [Check here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)
This Tutorial will help[tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/)

Send messages from the cloud

Send a message using GCM HTTP connection server protocol:

```
 https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
 Content-Type:application/json
 Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
 {
    "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
    "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
  }
 }
```

Handle a downstream message on an Android device:

```
 @Override
 public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
 String message = data.getString("message");
 Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
 Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
 // Handle received message here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But could I do it without cloud service, like with the help of server itself? Sorry if this question seems stupid..

Comment: Yes you client need to poll each other but its to resource intensive...and its not a practical method...

Comment: Oh! So, if I need to do it for multiple merchants and multiple users, using GCM service is my only option, am I correct?